# Return a value of the JSON object obtained from AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I'm trying to return a value from a JSON Object in a JS function, this is my code:

```
function verifyActive(numEmpleado){
    var id_codigo = 0;
    try{
        var dataString="oper=11&hidNumEmpleadoN="+numEmpleado;
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url:"./negReporteStatusHH.jsp",
                cache: false,
                data: dataString,
                datatype:"json",
                success: function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                    var jsonObj = data;
                    var jsonResult = JSON.parse(jsonObj);
                    var arr = [];
                    for(var x in jsonResult){
                        arr.push(jsonResult[x]);
                    }
                    console.log(arr[0]);
                    console.log(jsonResult);
                    id_codigo = arr[0];
                }
            });
            return id_codigo;
        }catch(e){
            return id_codigo;
        }
 }
```

The JSON Object obtained is the following:

```
{RIDCODIGO: 1, RDESCIDCODIGO: "WE HAVE DATA        ", RIDSTATUS: 1, RDESCIDSTATUS: "ACTIVE     "}
```

I want to return the `RIDCODIGO` value. Any question post on comments.

Comment: Are you asking how to get a value by key in an object in javascript? `obj.key`.

Comment: I'm asking how can i return the value ´RIDCODIGO´ of the JSON object. @h2ooooooo

Comment: By using `objname.RIDCODIGO`. As with any other object and any other key.